# FirebaseError: Function updateDoc() called with invalid data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I'm writing a function uploadPost() inside that function I add a doc into firebase firestore collection than I choose a image and update doc by getting download url from firebase but I getting error like

```html
FirebaseError: Function updateDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Promise object (found in field image in document posts/mcux46HsSK4mxycOIuev)
```

My function is given below

```html
const uploadPost = async () => {
        if (loading) return;

        setLoading(true);

        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), {
            username: session.user.username,
            caption: captionRef.current.value,
            profileImg: session.user.image,
            timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
        })

        const imageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${docRef.id}/image`);

        await uploadString(imageRef, selectedFile, 'data_url').then(async (snapshot) => {
            const downloadUrl = getDownloadURL(imageRef);
            await updateDoc(doc(db, 'posts', docRef.id), {
                image: downloadUrl
            });
        });

        setOpen(false);
        setLoading(false);
        setSelectedFile(null);
    }
```

What is wrong with that please give some suggestions for this.

Comment: Is `getDownloadURL` an async function? If so, you have to `await` it to get the `downloadUrl` value, otherwise you're just passing a promise to the `image` property in the `updateDoc` call (which may explain the error).

Comment: In addition, you do not need to use "async-await" and "then-catch" together. Each can be used with Promises but not both of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
const uploadPost = async () => {
        if (loading) return;

        setLoading(true);

        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db,'posts'), {
            username: data?.user?.username, 
            caption: captionRef.current.value,
            profileImg: data?.user?.image,
            timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
        })

        const storage = getStorage(app);

        const imageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${docRef.id}/image`);

     await uploadString(imageRef, selectedFile, "data_url").then(async () => {
           const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
           console.log('this is it' , downloadURL);
           await updateDoc(doc(db, 'posts', docRef.id) , {
            image: downloadURL,
           })
        }).catch((err) => {console.log(err)})

        setOpen(false);
        setLoading(false);
        setSelectedFile(null);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses I resolve my code.